# Kiwifruit - slow drying

Tags: refrigerator, drying, kiwifruit

Last year, I accidentally slow dried some yellow kiwifruit in my refrigerator. I had simply forgotten about them. It must have been at least four months before I realized. When I pulled them out, still in their plastic container, they were in no way rotted, moldy or even soft. They seemed to have slowly dehydrated and reminded me of giant raisins. Let me tell you, they were AMAZING. The flavors were so intense! Does anyone know of a system or actual method for this? I want to do try this as a regular thing, but I also do not want to waste kiwifruit...and to have my hopes and dreams dashed upon the rocks because it did not work again.

Answer (score 2):

I think you were just lucky in that they didn't go moldy or rot in your refrigerator.  So, if you want more control, it would be a simple matter of peeling, slicing and dehydrating.  You can do this in an oven set on it's lowest temperature, or more reliably by using a food dehydrator. You can certainly experiment with whole fruit or larger chunks, but I think slices are the way to go for ease of use and storage.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you no more advice than with any dried-fruit process.

- make sure the fruits do not touch
- make sure the fruits have appropriate airflow
- check periodically for any damaged or mouldy ones and discard as appropriate.

You should be able to achieve the first two points with an egg carton.

But if you want fast and reliable results and don't mind getting slices a dehydrator is probably your best bet.